# HTML5 video byte range requests from non-zero start byte

Tags: video, amazon-s3, html5-video

I am currently working on creating an HTML5 video player that can play videos hosted on Amazon s3. The videos on s3 will be very lengthy and I want the ability to make byte range requests for smaller chunks of the videos. The code I am currently using is shown below:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/video_name.mp4", true);
var range_req = 'bytes=0-1000000';
xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", range_req);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.style["margin-left"] = "300px";
    document.body.appendChild(video);
};
xhr.send();
```

Now, this code works perfectly when the start-byte in the range request header is 0 (as is shown in the code above). However, I also want to be able to make range requests for chunks that don't start at the beginning of the video (say Range: bytes=1000000-2000000). And this is what is not working. When I try to make this kind of range request, I send the request with the correct range and get an appropriate partial content response (206) from s3, but the video will not play. Any ideas on what I need to do to get this to work? As I mentioned earlier my goal is to be able to play chunks of the videos stored on s3 that don't start at the beginning (from byte 0).

Comment: Hi akyker20, I know this is very old, but did you find a solution to your problem eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to seek into an mp4 in this manner. mp4 is split into two major pieces, the 'moov' and the 'mdat'. The mdat contains the raw audio and video information, but it useless without the 'moov'. the 'moov' contains information about how to locate and decode the raw frames within the 'mdat'. starting at 0 works, because the 'moov' is at the start of the file (in your case). So by starting after fter the moov, you download raw frames, but the deocder has no idea what format these frames are in, or even when a frame begins and ends.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So are you telling me that given an mp4 file there is no way to extract a smaller chunk out of it that is playable? Is it possible to make two byte range requests... One for the 'moov' portion (although this is difficult because I imagine it is not constant length) and a second for the chunk of interest and then append the byte streams together to form something that is playable? I just need some sort of solution.

Comment: Yes, that is very possible, and is how the <video> tag works by default, You can start by doing a range request for the first 8 bytes, This will likely be an ftyp atom. (first 4 bytes are 'ftyp' The next 4 bytes are the atom size. You can then leap frog aground the file to find and parse all the atoms. Note: This will take A LOT of code. Atoms are hierarchical, and you will need to parse about 30 different types. And many are in a compact format.

Comment: @szatmary You might be able to answer my questions. If it is not too much trouble can you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71091457/)