# How to properly serve the html5 player with partial content with 206 header when content length is zero for a limited time

Tags: node.js, http, https, html5-video, streaming

I am running a NodeJS server that is serving a video file to an html5 video player. The html5 player makes range requests to the server and plays the content as expected. Skipping parts of the video by scrubbing on the timeline works fine. But I need a bit of custom behavior in the request handler that serves the partial content. What I am doing right now is, Upon receiving a range request I am often sending less than what the original request asked with the following headers

```
// example range requested
bytes=0-1000/1000
// what I serve
status=206
bytes=0-4/1000
content-length=5
```

Lucky for me the html5 player automatically makes a subsequent request after receiving each partial response. After seeing this I was quite confident that I could even send ZERO bytes and it will keep making the request.

```
// example range requested
bytes=5-1000/1000
// what I serve
status=206
bytes=0-0/1000
content-length=0
```

Now in this case, after this request finishes the html5 player stops making any requests altogether. Should I exclude the range header in this case? Should I set the range to be 5-5/1000 but this still means 1 byte.

The reason why I am looking for something like this is, parts of the files are being processed before they are ready to serve.

Comment: “Should” is a loaded term here. You “should” be responding with the exact byte range that is asked for. Because it works in one player/browser does not means it will work others. This is a violation of the standard and because it seems to work today, does not mean it will continue to work next browser update.

Comment: I need a source to confirm that the server "has to" respond with the "exact" asked for range. Because majority of the times player only specifies the range start like `bytes=3-`, that's it.

Comment: If you need to provide video in chunks then consider using the **Media Source Extensions** part of the HTM5 video API. This allows you to send a bytes Array (buffer) to the video player, which stays "open" for more data at a later time (when your file is ready on server, read it and add it to queue with the "Append Buffer" command). Not sure what format your "video" is encoded as (MP4? WebM?, raw H264?, raw VP8/9?) but test the MSE system because It's safer than just slicing random bytes (lucky your video plays but every player needs a keyframe so how does that exist if you slice 0-5 bytes???)

Comment: @VC.One I only need to support MP4. Can you let me know a little more. Is MSE like an class which I can make an instance of with a file URL. If so then what kind of requests I can expect on the server side. Would they be range-requests or something else ? I tried the MDN page on it it has very surface level information about it.

Comment: @VC.One From what I am reading, I need to have the file on the server be in a certain way for it be used by MSE client side. But the MP4s are I am serving aren't fully available on the server. Their parts are are being "processed" before they are available so I wont be able to "precondition" them to be accessible via MSE.

Comment: For MSE then yes your MP4s must in a certain format called **fragmented MP4**. It's possible you already have this format since you say the parts are still being processed. Y'see the way an MP4 is structured is that the header already lists the byte positions of keyframes (also the total frames and their byte sizes). MP4 is a stored file to download, not streamed live as-you-go (hence f-MP4 was created for streaming). It's "fragmented" because each piece is like a separate MP4 file. Is there anyway to check your bytes (print to console)?

Comment: @VC.One When I say my MP4 are being processed before served. I was just using an umbrella term. A more correct description of what is happening is, that the mp4 that my server is serving is being downloaded from another source. It is a normal mp4 (no indefinite length). When stream starts I do have info like total number of bytes in file, first and last 4 MBs of file. it is only the middle that is slowly availed over time. So with these constraint do I have a reasonable way to pipe this data gracefully with spinner indicator in the html5 player